# restrict user from not entering more than 5 characters in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an input field. I want that user cannot enter more than 5 characters in input field. I have applied maxlength but it is not working as expected. Is there any other way to restrict?

*my component.html*

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" [formControl]="myName" (onChange)="nameChanges($event)">
```

*my component.ts file*

```
nameChanges(value: any){
   if(value.length>6){
     // restrict user from entering any character          
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding maxlength to your input should work:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" maxlength="5" [formControl]="myName">
```

Ideally you'll also want to validate your formControl:

```js
myName = new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(5));
```